# How to remove default menu context from contextmenu

Tags: html, css

I wrote contextmenu, but it displaying default menu item in it, which i don't require. I need to display only the menu which i specify (trial and share (twitter and facebook)). Im unable to remove back,forward,reload,etc menu from the context menu appearance. Please help me how to fix this issue.

jsfiddle for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/JQ86B/

Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Context Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
<div contextmenu="supermenu" id="gotit">
  <h1>Right click here to see the context </h1>
</div>

<menu type="context" id="supermenu">
 <menuitem label="trial" onclick="alert('Smile please')"></menuitem>
  <menu label="share">
    <menuitem label="twitter" onclick="alert('foo')"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="facebook" onclick="alert('bar')"></menuitem>
  </menu>
</menu>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nlsbshtr i refereed the same link only.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contextmenu.asp :

> The contextmenu attribute is not currently supported in any of the major browsers.

Comment: Do you refer another way which i can achieve context-menu implementation. Which will be very helpful.

Comment: The contextmenu attribute is new in HTML5. im using HTML5 only so only i asked.